# ReactJS - How to add a key value pair to an array?

Tags: arrays, reactjs, hash, react-props

In react app, I am trying to add a key value pair data to an existing data but it doesn't work.

Current static data is,

```
const result = [{
 {id: 0, important: false, name: "Shruthi R", phone: "9834233433", email: "shruthi@gmail.com", work: "NicheSoft", city: "Mysore"},
 {id: 1, important: false, name: "Paridhi Sharma", phone: "8856544422", email: "paridhi@gmail.com", work: "MicroTech", city: "Lucknow"}
];
```

I am trying to add data to this `result` via form and getting data in `this.props.location.state` format.

Now I want to add `id` to an newly created data `{important: false, name: "Sona", phone: "23423433", email: "sona@yopmail.com", work: "IBM", city: "Delhi"}`

I have tried to add it in this

```
this.setState(Object.assign(this.props.location.state, {id: result.length}))
this.setState({list: result.concat(this.props.location.state)});
```

way, but it has added separately like `[{...}, id: 3]`. How can I add `id` to the recently added hash data?

I want an output like `{important: false, name: "Sona", phone: "23423433", email: "sona@yopmail.com", work: "IBM", city: "Delhi", id: 3}` or `{id: 3, important: false, name: "Sona", phone: "23423433", email: "sona@yopmail.com", work: "IBM", city: "Delhi"}` and this should get append to an existing `result` array.

Comment: `const newArray = [...result, {...this.props.location.state, id:3}]`

Comment: To add into existing list state use like this.setState(prevList => ({list: [...prevList, {...this.props.location.state, id:3}]}))

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this approach,

```
this.setState(prev => ({list: [...prev, {...this.props.location.state, id:3}] })
```

```js
const arr = [
 {id: 0, important: false, name: "Shruthi R", phone: "9834233433", email: "shruthi@gmail.com", work: "NicheSoft", city: "Mysore"},
 {id: 1, important: false, name: "Paridhi Sharma", phone: "8856544422", email: "paridhi@gmail.com", work: "MicroTech", city: "Lucknow"}
];

const result = {important: false, name: "Sona", phone: "23423433", email: "sona@yopmail.com", work: "IBM", city: "Delhi"};


const newArray = [...arr, {...result, id:3}]

console.log(newArray);
```

Answer (score 0):

I see at least two quick solutions:

1. You create your object (including its id property) and then you add it to the result array.
2. You add the id property to the last object in your result array (since you talk about "newly created data" I am assuming it is always the last item). If this is the case, you can get the last item in your result array by using `result.length -1`